# Weird problem on airbase-ng

Tags: wireless, aircrack-ng

The situation is pretty simple, I'm trying to create a rogue AP, am I missing something? No matter what I do I get the same error message:

[image: Unable to create tap interface using airbase-ng]

I tried using different bssid and essid's with the corresponding names and channels.

Killed the processes, downed the interface, up again.

I deleted wlan0mon, disconnected the antenna from vm, then physically, reconnected everything, made some tests with different tools, airebase-ng still not working.

No problem with aircrack, airmon, airodump, aireplay, they all work.

If it's of any help I am using an Alfa AWUS036H 802.11 b/g wireless USB adapter
iwconfig:
[image: Wireless card is configured in monitor mode]

And the correct drivers are installed:
[image: output from dmesg]

The worst thing is there is not indication of error in the command syntax or a parameter missing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post an image without blurring information...
Maybe you're just adding a blank space on the ESSID and jumping a command, add quotes on strings, like this:

```
airbase-ng -c 11 -a AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA --essid 'I use blanks on my essid' wlan0mon
```

Try this to test:

```
airbase-ng -c 2 --essid test -a AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA wlan0mon
```

or without the `-a` (Use your default MAC)

```
airbase-ng -c 2 --essid test wlan0mon
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want create  rogue AP,
 with a lot of things automated do check WiFi Pumpkin a good framework for it**.

[**WIFI Pumpkin**](https://github.com/P0cL4bs/WiFi-Pumpkin)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell with the deprecated details, however if there spaces in the ESSID then try adding quotes around the name.